# Applescript to read notifications to the Apps in Dock

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to be able to have a script which can detects if I have new messages in my messaging apps.. Slack, lync,.

Is it possible to use applescript to read if there is any active notification on the apps in the Dock..

Comment: Short answer here is _No_, which refers equally to using AppleScript in trying to achieve your ultimate goal.  Longer answer is that you might be able to use AppleScriptObjC in a _Stay Open_ application that monitors incoming notifications sent to the some notification centre of choice (there are a few), but ultimately you'd end up polling for every notification, or perhaps a select few, and either way it's an expensive use of system resources for what I would perceive as the benefit to such an objective.  So, even if it's possible, it's inadvisable, so the answer is still _No_.

Comment: Do you wish to get an automatic notification when a message arrives, or just an app you start yourself that looks for you, saving you some keystrokes/mouse clicks?

Comment: @clemsamlang I wish to get notifications to my tmux staus line.. So if I am able to somehow detect a new message has arrived, my app can initiate the rest of the pipeline which makes tmux to display the information

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

> `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`/com.apple.notificationcenter/db

(which line I found at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156832/where-osx-10-10-notification-center-settings-are-stored)), you'll get returned:

> /var/folders/_d/pg2g_[some_funny_numbers]/0//com.apple.notificationcenter/db: is a directory

Inside this/my folder I found:

> db   db-shm    db-wal    db2upgraded

When some action happens (I sent a notification) only `db-wal` gets updated (nearly) at once.

So, in principle it should be possible to write an AS (saved as Stay Open app) that periodically looks if "db-wal" has changed (comparing saved sizes or change dates) and, *ONLY if so*, searches it for some keywords (Slack, lync,…) again comparing # of occurrences, thus learning if s.th. new has arrived. Admittedly sounds awkward but could work.

It would be much more elegant to use a folder script, but as no file is moved nor a folder opened/closed such a script can not be invoked.

Comment: I have to agree with what CJK said in his comment to the OP as AppleScript Stay Open applications are typically not worth the resource drain that can occur over time depending of how  short the `return` is set in the `idle` _handler_. I believe that using `launchd` and `WatchPaths` on a target file is much more efficient use of resources then an AppleScript Stay Open applications. Just some food for thought.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating  just in a few words how 2 use `launchd` and `WatchPaths` in a simple example? If I started reading into those it'd take me a lot of time to discover even the most obvious uses, as I've never used them. Thanks! . . . . . Btw: do you know of a way to make folder ASs work except by opening or adding files?

Comment: Have a look at Monitoring a Directory in [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) and note that `WatchPaths` can point to a file too. As to the  ... Btw: ..., no, and have a look at Write a Folder Action Script in [Watching Folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html)  the event handlers supported by folder actions as defined in the Standard Additions scripting addition.

Comment: I _HAVE_ looked into `WatchPaths` and found that it behaves a lot like Folder AS in that it will only take notice when files are added or deleted. While apparently some apps (like TextEdit) do "re-write" files when saving changes and therefore are "detected", sadly NotificationCenter's `db-wal` file is _NOT_ re-written when saved anew… So you'd have to use a `<key>StartInterval…` just like I suggested using a Stay-Open-AS. Not _MUCH_ of a difference IMHO.